# Excel Macro Error Runtime Error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a runtime error with the following code in the 'do stuff' section.  Attached is the file - I'm getting the error when I click "Retrieve Scorecard" on the 'Control' tab.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/t8ebv4cl1ms1t2v/010714_NS_Scorecard%20-%20New%20Prototype_V3.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Can you please post your code here? I don't know if too many people (myself included) are going to download a link to some file on the internet (*especially* one in which we need to allow Macros to run.)

Comment: Beyond the inherent security issue mentioned by @BruceWayne, this question is useless for any future purpose without posted code annotated to indicate what line is throwing the error as well as the error message itself. Becoming part of the [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) community means more that getting your own problem answerd; it means that you are contributing to a repository of Q&A that will help others with the same problem.

Comment: works fine (no error detected)... case solved :D

Comment: My apologies, I'm new here and I'm still learning the proper way to post.

@DirkReichel you don't get an error?

Comment: Nope.... If i select a customer and hit the button, no error pops up... (also checked the code as good as possible and there shouldn`t be any errors... please tell me your excel version, which cell was selected when hittig the button and the exact error-text... also if a line is marked as "here is an error", pls tell me which...

Comment: I don't get an error, maybe you should also check if the activecell is in column A as well before showing the msgbox

Comment: @DirkReichel I am using excel 2011 for Mac.  When i go to the control tab and click "retrieve scorecard" a Microsoft visual basic error comes up reading: 'run-time error '424': Object required'

Comment: which cell is selected when klicking the button?

Comment: @DirkReichel cell A3

Comment: @DirkReichel the solution seemed to work, however the control tab disappears after the action has been completed

Answer (score 0):

try to replace the 4 lines after `' do stuff` with

```
wScorecard.Cells(5, 2).Value = wData.Cells(iSel, 1).Value
wScorecard.Cells(7, 2).Value = wData.Cells(iSel, 2).Value
wScorecard.Cells(8, 2).Value = wData.Cells(iSel, 3).Value
wScorecard.Cells(9, 2).Value = wData.Cells(iSel, 4).Value
```

and check if that still pops up the error

**EDIT**

please save your workbook as a new workbook and change this 2 subs:

```
Sub RetrieveScorecard()

  'This macro will show the overview tab
  Dim iSel As Integer
  Dim i As Long

  Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  If ActiveCell.Value = "" Or ActiveCell.Row < 3 Then MsgBox "No Supplier Selected!", vbOKOnly: Exit Sub

  If Not MsgBox("You have selected " & ActiveCell.Value & ". Do you want to retrieve this supplier?", vbYesNoCancel + vbInformation, "Retrieve Scorecard") = vbYes Then MsgBox "All action stopped", vbOKOnly: Exit Sub

  Sheets("Scorecard").Visible = True

  With Sheets("Data")
    .Visible = True
    iCol = .Cells(.Columns(1).Cells.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For iSel = 2 To iCol
      If .Cells(iSel, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Value Then Exit For
    Next
    iCol = 1
  End With

  ' do stuff
  For i = 0 To 3
    Sheets("Scorecard").Cells(Array(5, 7, 8, 9)(i), 2).Value = Sheets("Data").Cells(iSel, i + 1).Value
  Next

  'Updates PQScore field to the correct selection
  With Sheets("Scorecard")
    For i = 0 To 18
      iRow = Sheets("Data").Cells(iSel, 5 + i).Value
      RetrieveValueList (.Cells(Array(14, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 26, 27, 28, 32, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 45, 46, 47, 48)(i), 3))
    Next
  End With

  Sheets("Scorecard").Cells(10, 2).Value = Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 27)
  Sheets("Scorecard").Cells(11, 2).Value = Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 28)

  Sheets("Control").Visible = False
  Sheets("Scorecard").Select

  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Sub RetrieveValueList(rSel As Range)

  With Sheets("Scorecard")
    If iRow = 1 Or iRow = 2 Or iRow = 3 Then
      .Cells(rSel.Row, 2).Value = Range(.Cells(rSel.Row, 2).Validation.Formula1)(4 - iRow)
    Else
      .Cells(rSel.Row, 2).Value = ""
    End If
  End With

  Sheets("Data").Select

End Sub
```

then check for errors...

Comment: That seemed to work, but i now get an error at the following lines:

    [GTCValue].Value = Cells(iRow, iCol + 26)
    [GTCModified_Value].Value = Cells(iRow, iCol + 27)

Comment: @EricMoore i've edited my answer, please try that... it seems that the `ActiveSheet`-reference caused this trouble... you may only need to add the `Sheets("xyz").` to your ranges... jumping over 50 times between the sheets and refer to the "active" doesnt work out as it should...

Comment: This works - however the control tab disappears after it retrieves the suppliers scorecard

Comment: it was more like a check if you still get that error, its like a complete rewrite of your macro... pls try to not use direct references (the other macros may also be rewritten, but it wont help if you dont know how it works, so you need to do it yourself) :D